# Como esperar a resposta de uma função assíncrona(Javascript/Cordova)?

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, assincronismo, cordova-plugin

Estou desenvolvendo um app Cordova e estou utilizando o plugin Sqlite para fazer consultas no banco de dados. Porém como as funções de querys são assincronas estou com um problema para criar um array multidimensional.

```
tx.executeSql("select que pesquisa os grupos", [], function(tx, grupos) {

    var arrayGrupos = []; // Cria uma variavel para armazenar os grupos
    for(grupoAtual in grupos) { // faz o loop pelos grupos

        var arrayItensGrupos = []; // Cria uma variavel para armazenar os itens dos grupos
        tx.executeSql("select que pesquisa os itens dos grupos", [], function(tx, itensGrupos) {

            for(itemAtual in itensGrupos) { // faz o loop pelos itens dos grupos

                detalhesItem = { // Cria o item
                    nomeItem: itemAtual.nome_item
                    ...
                }
                arrayItensGrupos.push(detalhesItem); // Adiciona o item ao array

            }

        }

        detalhesGrupo = { // Cria o grupo
            nomeGrupo: grupoAtual.nome_grupo,
            listadeItens: arrayItensGrupos //** adiciona o array com os itens
        }
        arrayGrupos.push(detalhesGrupo); // Adiciona o grupo ao array

    }

});
```

Quando dou um `console.log` no array de grupos (`arrayGrupos`) ele me retorna os grupos com o nome certo, porém o array com a lista de itens do grupo (`listadeItens: arrayItensGrupos`) vem vazia. Alguns grupos tem varios itens e outros não, nesses com poucos itens vem a lista normal porém no grupo que demora um pouco mais ele não espera retornar todos os itens(pela função ser assincrona) e mostra como se a lista estivesse vazia.

Então tem como esperar a função `executeSql`(assíncrona) retornar o resultado para prosseguir?

Answer (score 1):

O quão confortável você está com JavaScript? Para esperar pela resposta você pode utilizar `Promise`. Isso torna até mais fácil de optimizar a consulta, pois você pode utilizar métodos da classe Promise para realizar varias queries de forma assíncrona, sem que uma tenha que esperar pela resposta da outra, como seria o ideal no seu laço `for`.

Para a pergunta, eu sugiro a solução abaixo. se você ainda não está familiarizado com Promises, async e await, recomendo que leia a documentação ou faça uma nova pergunta.

```
// Transformo o método numa função que retorna Promises
const executeSQL = (query, arr) => new Promise(resolve => tx.executeSQL(query, arr, (tx, grupo) => resolve(grupo)))

// Faço a query dos grupos utilizando await
var grupos = await executeSql("select que pesquisa os grupos", [])
// Faço todas as queries dos itens simultaneamente, e espero por elas finalizarem
var itensGrupos = await Promise.all(grupos.map(grupoAtual => executeSql("select que pesquisa os itens dos grupos", [])))

// Monto o array
var arrayGrupos = grupos.map((grupo, i) => ({
    nomeGrupo: grupo.nome_grupo,
    listadeItens: itensGrupos[i].map(item => ({
        nomeItem: item.nome_item
        // ...
    }))
}))
```

Comment: Cara confesso que por mais que eu tenha avançado e bastante no javascript não sei porque não consegui aprender os `Promise's`, já li a documentação mas achei meio confuso sei lá, vou testar a sua resposta que está parecendo bem simples de implementar em minhas outras funções.